# Unitalicise part of x-axis text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ficticious data frame of average canine length of African Wolf subspecies compared to the domestic dog:

```
library(ggplot2)

canids <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 7, ncol = 2))
names(canids) <- c("length", "species")
canids[,1] <- runif(7, min=3, max=10)
canids[,2] <- c("C. lupaster subsp. algirensis",
                "C. lupaster subsp. anthus",
                "C. lupaster subsp. bea",
                "C. lupaster subsp. lupaster",
                "C. lupaster subsp. riparius",
                "C. lupaster subsp. soudanicus",
                "C. familiaris")

ggplot(canids, aes(x = species, y = length)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Canine length (cm) \n") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "italic", size = 13),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 13))
```

[image: plot]

To stick with convention, I would like to unitalicise the "subsp." portion of the x-axis text for each subspecies, but keep the rest of it in italics. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use `ggtext::element_markdown()` by inserting the `*` in the 'species' column with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
canids %>%
  mutate(species = case_when(str_detect(species, "subsp\\.") ~ 
  str_replace(species, "(.*)\\s+(subsp.)\\s+(.*)", "*\\1* \\2 *\\3*"),
    TRUE ~ str_c("*", species, "*"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(species, y = length)) + 
   geom_col() + 
   xlab("") +
   ylab("Canine length (cm) \n") +
   theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

-output

[image]